# Netbeans Manual upload

Tags: netbeans

Running Netbeans 6.9.1 in Ubuntu 10.04. Automatic upload of files on save to remote sftp server is working, but if I set it to manual and try to upload with the right click context menu, it won't upload or give the file selection box, but opens the project properties window instead. What am I missing?

Comment: Just reopen project, it's works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Projects' window (CTRL+1) right click NOT on your project, but on the 'Source Files' folder below it. There you choose 'Upload'.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to upload the files from the 'files' tab.

Which is inappropriate to a project file to upload.

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
2. A project window would show-up
3. Now rightclick the files and folders there to upload.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your own shortcut to upload the *selected file*/*the file you edit now*.

1. Tools -> Options -> Keymap
2. Find "Upload..." action in actions list
3. Enter your shortcut. For example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

That's it. When you're in fullscreen mode, it is easy to upload your file using keyboard shortcuts only.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around (semi-manual upload :p):

1. Give each project 2 run configurations (in project properties). Use the default for working locally and add a second for working and uploading remotely.
2. Set the second remote run configuration to 'Upload on run'.
3. Click OK to close the project properties.
4. Once you are ready to upload your local website to the remote location, select the second run configuration in the top toolbar of Netbeans and RUN your project (F6).

I hope this helps.